# R - Error T-test For loop command between variables

Tags: r

Currently in the process of writing a For Loop that'll calculate and print t-test results, I'm testing for the difference in means of all variables (faminc, fatheduc, motheduc, white, cigtax, cigprice) between smokers and non-smokers ("smoke"; 0=non, 1=smoker)

Current code:

```
type <- c("faminc", "fatheduc", "motheduc", "white", "cigtax", "cigprice")
count <- 1
for(name in type){
  temp <- subset(data, data[name]==1)
  cat("For", name, "between smokers and non, the difference in means is: \n")
  print(t.test(temp$smoke))
  count <- count + 1
}
```

However, I feel that 'temp' doesn't belong here and when running the code I get:

```
For faminc between smokers and non, the difference in means is: 
Error in t.test.default(temp$smoke) : not enough 'x' observations
```

The simple code of

```
t.test(faminc~smoke,data=data)
```

does what I need, but I'd like to get some practice/better understanding of for loops.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that generates the output requested in the OP, using `lapply()` with the `mtcars` data set.

```
data(mtcars)
varList <- c("wt","disp","mpg")
results <- lapply(varList,function(x){
  t.test(mtcars[[x]] ~ mtcars$am)
})
names(results) <- varList
for(i in 1:length(results)){
      message(paste("for variable:",names(results[i]),"difference between manual and automatic transmissions is:"))
      print(results[[i]])
}
```

...and the output:

```
> for(i in 1:length(results)){
+   message(paste("for variable:",names(results[i]),"difference between manual and automatic transmissions is:"))
+   print(results[[i]])
+ }
for variable: wt difference between manual and automatic transmissions is:

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  mtcars[[x]] by mtcars$am
t = 5.4939, df = 29.234, p-value = 6.272e-06
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.8525632 1.8632262
sample estimates:
mean in group 0 mean in group 1 
       3.768895        2.411000 

for variable: disp difference between manual and automatic transmissions is:

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  mtcars[[x]] by mtcars$am
t = 4.1977, df = 29.258, p-value = 0.00023
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
  75.32779 218.36857
sample estimates:
mean in group 0 mean in group 1 
       290.3789        143.5308 

for variable: mpg difference between manual and automatic transmissions is:

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  mtcars[[x]] by mtcars$am
t = -3.7671, df = 18.332, p-value = 0.001374
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -11.280194  -3.209684
sample estimates:
mean in group 0 mean in group 1 
       17.14737        24.39231 

>
```

Answer (score 0):

Compare your code that works...

```
t.test(faminc~smoke,data=data)
```

You are specifying a relationship between variables (`faminc~smoke`) which means that you think the mean of `faminc` is different between the values of `smoke` and you wish to use the `data` dataset.

The equivalent line in your loop...

```
  print(t.test(temp$smoke))
```

...only gives the single column of `temp$smoke` after having selected those who have the value `1` for each of `faminc`, `fatheduc` etc.  So even if you wrote...

```
print(t.test(faminc~smoke, data=data))
```

Further your `count` is doing nothing.

If you want to perform a range of testes in this manner you could

```
type <- c("faminc", "fatheduc", "motheduc", "white", "cigtax", "cigprice")
for(name in type){
  cat("For", name, "between smokers and non, the difference in means is: \n")
  print(t.test(name~smoke, data=data))
}
```

Whether this is what you want to do though isn't clear to me, your variables suggest family (`faminc`), father (`fatheduc`), mother (`motheduc`), ethnicity (`white`), tax (`cigtax`) and price (`cigprice`).

I can't think why you would want to compare the mean cigarette price or tax between smokers and non-smokers, because the later are not going to have any value for this since they don't smoke!

You're code suggests these are perhaps binary variables though (since you are filtering on each value being `1`) which to me suggests this isn't even what you want to do.

If you wish to look in subsets of data then a [tidier](https://www.tidyverse.org) approach to performing regression rather than loops is to use [purrr](https://purrr.tidyverse.org).

In future when asking consider providing a sample of data along with the full copy & pasted output as advised in [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example - Help Center - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Because this allows people to see in greater detail what you are doing (e.g. I've only guessed about your variables).  With statistics its also useful to state what your hypothesis is too to help people understand what it is you are trying to achieve overall.